# Custom Pipe Not Found

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having issues with a custom pipe not being found when I call it.

I have imported the pipe in my app.module.ts file and declared it in the declarations. I followed a few tutorials on how to do it and also have looked at a few questions already asked on here and by what I am seeing it should work but it is still throwing the error: "The pipe 'getOrderType' could not be found"

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'getOrderType'})
export class GetOrderTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(orderType: String, delivered: Boolean, requestType: String): LoadTypeEnum {
        if (delivered&& requestType !== 'mobile') {
            return 'Mobile devlivery';
          } else if (requestType === 'web') {
            return 'Web';
          } else {
            return 'N/A';
          }
    }
}
```

and here is how I am calling it in my html:

```
{{ this.orderType| getOrderType: this.order.requestType: this.delivered}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere youare using the PipeName as **`getLoadType`** instead of **`getOrderType`**

**QuickFix**: do a free text search on the source code and do a replace with getOrderType.

Comment: Whoops good catch. i forgot to change that while changing the name. I updated the error message to mroe accurately represent it since I am still getting the same error but with the correct name.

Comment: are you using it in the same app module component or different module?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you import your pipe because it looks like its missing in your module.ts providers:

```
providers: [
        GetOrderTypePipe
    ]
```

Comment: I have a parent component and a child component. Child component is where I need the pipe. I imported it in the parent component's module.ts and declared it in the declaration and put it in the provider. Still not working, I could be wrong as to where it should go though.

Comment: I just know if I have the info in any other module VSCode gives me the error. If I have it in the parent component's module it throws the error when running the tests.

Comment: You dont have to import anything in your component. It needs to be in the providers of the module where your components are.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided to just delete everything regarding to the pipe and redo the ng generate pipe and it works fine (It looks identical to what I had it as which is what has me thrown off but, as of now it works) I appreciate your time.